# water leak in ceiling -- how to proceed

Tags: plumbing, water, ceiling, leak

I just noticed that there are two *new* water leak stain marks in my kitchen ceiling --- cf the zoom out photo.  I'd really appreciate help and advice on how to proceed.
The zoom-out photo actually has 3 stainmarks so let me explain.

In the zoom-out photo there is one stain mark, to the left of the vent outlet, and two stain marks to the right.  Right about the kitchen is a full-bathroom.  The left stain mark is right above the toilet; this stainmark has been there for 5+ years.  A plumber checked it out suspected that the wax ring (?) might have dried out and water creeped through when I moped the bathroom.  He didn't think it was a big deal and just asked me to keep an eyes on it.  It has not gotten bigger/worse over this 5+ years, and it is dry to touch now.

The two *new* stain marks were not there at this year's Thanksgiving, but otherwise I can't pin point the time where they appeared.  I touched the stainmarks and they are sticky.  The rightmost one is about 12"x9", and for reference the circiular disk is 5" in diameter.  Currently there is no liquid dripping down from these stain marks.  Right about the two stainmarks is a sink/faucet.  I just checked and the (exposed) pipes of the faucets are dry-to-touch, and there is no watermark anywhere in the upstair bathroom.   The 2nd floor area above the right edge of the photo is a bathtub.  There is no visible sign of waterleak around the tub.

I am at a loss of how/what to proceed.  Do I call a plumber?  Handyman? etc?  Obvioulsy (?) the first step is to fix the leak, but is it even possible to identify the source without cutting open the ceiling?  Is that a big job?  Should I shutoff the water for the faucet/toilet/tub for now? -- but it's freezing outside and I don't want the pipe to burst...

Your help and advice is truly appreciated.

PS:  I'm the home owner in case that matters.

[image: water leak, zoom out]

[image: water leak in kitchen ceiling, zoom in]

Comment: Usually bathroom floors are tiled.  Drywall of the ceiling much easier to fix.  If the pipes are not in an outside wall, freezing chance is near zero.  If the pipes are dry above/pass the valves then probably won't work to stop the leaking.  Is there an access hatch in the wall for the plumbing, or just in cabinet?

Comment: Thanks @crip659.  The bathroom is indeed tiled and the ceiling is drywall + stucco.  Years ago I did have problem with a frozen (but not bursted) pipe in a facuet/sink *near* the one above these new stainmarks.  It hasn't happened since but I'm always weary about frozen pipe.   There is a small acess hatch for the bathtub plumbing, but not for the toilet and faucet above the new stain marks.   And I'm baffled why the stain mark is "sticky" to touch.

Comment: I would blame it on bathtub. Stop using it and use heat gun to dry the ceiling to know if it is bathtub leaking.

Comment: Thanks @Ruskes.  May I ask why you think it's the tub, and how to heat gun to test if the leak is from the tub?  The  faucet/sink of the tub is situated near the top right corner of the zoom-out photo, so if the leak is from the tub I thought (???) there would be a stain mark there?  THANKS for your help!

Comment: Heat gun will dry the drywall, if the stains appear again then you would know where they come from. The problem with frozen pipes is they do not always burst, but get small cracks. possibly not the pipes but the connections are damaged. Either rubber seals or compression fittings. You should be able to check those. Go upstairs and take picture

Comment: Dampness(does not need much) on a ceiling/wall will tend to collect dust/dirt/sticky stuff from the air first.  If you google ceiling joist shadow can see some pictures of it.

Comment: Thanks Ruskes.  What types of pictures should I take?  The exposed pipes of the  faucets? Toilet? Tub?

Comment: Thanks @Ruskes.  I was able to google pictures of "ceiling joist shadow", and I don't see anything like that anywhere at home.  And like I said the two new stain marks appear after Thanksgiving this year.

Comment: How does the vent outlet work?  All I can see is a box in the ceiling.

Comment: Thanks for asking @huesmann.  Plumbers cut 2 holds in ceiling & found no interior leaks.  The stainmarks are right below the roofline of the kithcen extension; that turns out to be a known source of water leak.  Condo assoc sent roofers to fix the outside of several units, including mine; since then the stainmarks has not gotten bigger.  Right now I taped a clear plastic sheet over the open squares; I'll monitor the stainmarks for a couple more months in case there are additional issues, and then negotiate with the condo assoc. re internal repairs.  I appreciate adivce re the latter -- THANKS!

Comment: @underflow I would consider getting a yardstick or similar (tape measure?), tape it in place, lining it up with the ceiling box, and taking photographs.  In the future, you should be able to line up the yardstick in the same way and compare the size of the stains.  Just taking photos without something to give you a scale reference it's hard to tell changes in size over time.